# Game theory, dividing a number into parts.

Tags: combinatorics

The number $10^{2018}$ is written on the blackboard. Alice and Bob play a game where each
player in turn makes one of the two following operations:

1. Erase a number $x$ on the blackboard and replace it with two positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $x = ab$. (Note that $a = b$ is permitted, and in such a case $x$ is replaced by two copies of $a$.)
2. If a number $x$ occurs at least twice on the blackboard, erase one or two copies of $x$.

The player who is not able to make her turn loses the game.

If Alice begins, who has a winning strategy, and what is it?

---

I know that there are an even number of factors in total, but the second move can result in an odd number of factors. This gets really confusing, can I have a full solution to show how this is solved? I cannot even start.

Comment: Please edit  to include your efforts.  A typical starting point would be to work it for smaller starting numbers in the hope that a pattern emerges.  Note:  it's not clear to me that the game has a winning strategy as it is not clear that one player can even force it to terminate.  Proving that would be a good start.

Comment: If the only number on the blackboard is $n$, can you replace it with $1$ and $n$ since $n=1\times n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that the integers $a,b$ must be bigger than $1$, since otherwise the game need never end. If a number can only be split into proper factors, the game ends either when there are no numbers left on the board, or all the numbers on the board are single primes.

Alice's first move is to replace $10^{2018}$ by $2^{2018}$ and $5^{2018}$.
After that, anything that Alice and Bob can do involves either splitting a power of $2$ or splitting a power of $5$, or else deleting one or two powers of $2$ or one or two powers of $5$.

Suppose that at any stage of the game it is Bob's go and the numbers on the board are $2^{a(1)},2^{a(2)},\ldots,2^{a(n)}$ and $5^{a(1)},5^{a(2)},\ldots,5^{a(n)}$ for some integers $a(1),a(2),\ldots,a(n)$ (the collections of indices of the powers of $2$ and the powers of $5$ are the same). If Bob splits $2^{u+v}$ into $2^u$ and $2^v$, then Alice must be able to respond by splitting $5^{u+v}$ into $5^u$ and $5^v$. If Bob deletes one or more copies of $2^u$, then Alice must be able to respond by removing one or more copies of $5^u$. Similarly, if Bob's move affects a power of $5$, Alice must be able to respond with the matching move on the powers of $2$. Thus, whenever Bob is able to make a move, Alice can also move, and Bob is presented with a board where the collections of indices of the powers of $2$ and the powers of $5$ are the same.

Thus Bob must be the first person to be unable to move, and Alice wins.